# user.validatePassword is not a function

Tags: passport.js, sequelize-cli

```html
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const user = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
 password: DataTypes.STRING,
 status: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  user.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  user.validPassword =  function (password) console.log(this.password);
};
  return user;
};
```

Getting this error in node js
I am using  "sequelize": "^5.21.3",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KypaP.png)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
 user.validPassword =  function (password) { console.log(this.password) };
```

you are missing the curly braces.

or arrow function,

```
 user.validPassword =  password => console.log(this.password);
```

try this code:

```
'use strict';
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  user.associate = function (models) {

  };

  user.prototype.validPassword = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
  };
  return user;
};
```

hope this helps.

Comment: 'use strict';
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var  user = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
 password: DataTypes.STRING,
 status: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  user.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  
 user.prototype.validPassword =  function (password) {
   return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};
  return user;
};

Comment: updated my answer, can you save the code as a file and run it ?

Comment: `'use strict';
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var  user = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
 password: DataTypes.STRING,
 status: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  user.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  
 user.prototype.validPassword =  function (password) {
   return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
};
  

return user;
};`

Comment: [https://prnt.sc/qm687o] please open this image. in this image i have define the passport module.

Comment: I am not following you, can you create a GitHub gist and share me the file. Just show me the minimal reproduce-able code, because I ran this code and I didn't have any issues.

Comment: Please check this below url:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7632
User name : ravirathoreds